# Websockets- Multiple message types

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

So as researching websockets has shown me I should be using 1 websocket for all my needs. The problem with this is that my application sends many different message types and receives many different message types.

So for example I could be getting back data on a document, user, some settings, a chat message, etc. So I have MANY different message types and my onMessage on both server and client sides are getting messy with if statements to deal with the different messages.

So my question is what is a good way of dealing with this, whats the best coding practice.

Comment: Hi, Can you share some info how you solved this? I am having the same issue and not sure how to handle when we multiple message types?

Comment: I simply had to write code to take in different message types and run the appropriate after that. For me the easiest way was to make the message type the name of the class that was needed to run, create an object from that class name, run it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of different types of messages coming in why don't you make a script that has a function to deal with the payload's content. Since you have different messages types you will have to account for different types of payloads. Write a function in another file and import it into your socket file and it will be used to  evaluate the payload and give an appropriate response. Tailor this function might take some work.

I have used sockets in a few projects and sockets on both front and back end *only listen or emit*. I try to keep other logic separate so my code is more modular. Hope this helps also can you show an example of your code?

Comment: At the moment I am just doing testing as we are looking at the idea of moving from a REST service to a websocket one. So no code worth sharing but thanks for your answer.